# Do I have to hold the Power Jewel to use it?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Power Jewel (Advendurers Vault, p176):

> **Power ♦ Daily (Minor Action)**
> This power allows you to regain the use of an encounter power of 1st or 3rd level.

Do I have to get it from my backpack before using it?

What about items that are normally<sup>1</sup> used, like a Whistle of Warning<sup>2</sup>?

---

1. Normally meaning their mundane versions have some applications, as opposed to a Power Jewel
2. Adventurer's Vault 2, page 78: Encounter(Minor) Each ally within 10 squares of you who can hear the whistle can shift 1 square and draw a weapon or retrieve an implement as a free action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### RAW, wondrous items don't require items slots or being held unless they say they do.

For example, the *rope of climbing* in the PHB needs to be held in order to be commanded.

#### Also RAW, the DM can impose any requirements they like on using an item in combat if they believe it's officially reached "rigmarole" status.

> Depending on the object being manipulated, the Dungeon Master might require the acting creature to make a skill check or an ability check to successfully perform the desired task.
>
> -- "Manipulating Objects", *Rules Compendium* p. 244

#### If you're a player, ask your DM; if you're a DM, try and make a call in advance.

My general guide for ruling is that, unless they say otherwise, most wondrous items need to be "slotlessly equipped" - they need to adorn your person or gear somehow, but not in a way that takes up a magic item slot; some few items will say they only need to be carried to function.

Items that say you need to interact with them somehow - you need to blow a *horn of blasting* or scoop out and throw some *dust of appearance* - need a hand available to hold the item in order to use it, but don't need to be drawn or stowed; the horn can be slung around your shoulder, the dust pouch strapped to your belt.